# Why are there testing factor levels in a pure training set?

Tags: r, dataset

To illustrate I use the `segmentationOriginal` dataset from the `AppliedPredictiveModeling` package:

```
> library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
> data(segmentationOriginal)
> levels(factor(segmentationOriginal$Case))
[1] "Test"  "Train"
```

The authors of the data set have the training and testing data intermixed in the data set, so I wanted to separate the two types of data into separate data frames:

```
> training <- segmentationOriginal[segmentationOriginal$Case=="Train", ]
> testing <- segmentationOriginal[segmentationOriginal$Case=="Test", ]
```

However, the `Case` variable of the `training` data set still has two factor levels:

```
> str(training$Case)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "Test","Train": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

even if there is not a single `Test` factor in the `Case` variable any longer of the training set:

```
> which(training$Case == "Test")
integer(0)
```

Why is that or what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The elements of your `Case` factor can be one of two values ("levels"). An R's factor's levels defines the *possible* values, not just the current values. You may be misled by the default action for the `factor` function which creates levels corresponding to the values that exist in what you pass to it, but this is a one-time convenience and the factor levels are fixed at that time.